# Which is better: "related more" or "was more related"

Tags: past-tense, syntactic-analysis, adverb-position, passive-voice

> It actually related more to his genetics than his behavior.

or

> It actually was more related to his genetics than his behavior.

Comment: The contrast is usually made between genetics and environment ("nature vs.nurture") as causative; "behavior" is often considered a result of one or more of these formative factors.  It would help if you provided some context to show what "it" refers to.

Answer (score 1):

## *It actually was more related to his genetics than his behavior.*

or

### *It was actually more related to his genetics than his behavior.*

but not

*It actually related more to his genetics than his behavior.*

(The verb tense and the word *more* you use in this sentence makes the verb "relate" take another of its meanings, which is ["to understand and like or have sympathy for someone or something"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/relate). It wouldn't make sense because the subject of the sentence (*It*) is not human.)

---

The reason why the two first sentences are both acceptable is that the adverb "actually" is mobile in the sentence. You could also say *Actually, it was more related to his genetics than his behavior.*